# In WPF How can I increment the index of a ListBox inside of another ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to be able to access the index of a `ListBox` that is inside of another `ListBox` and increment that index. I tried to use `ItemContainerGenerator` but when I cast the Item as a `ListBox` or `ItemsControl` it returns `null`.

I would like to increment the index in code behind or a viewmodel.

here is the basic structure of my template

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">

            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"></Setter>

            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate >
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>

                        <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />-->
                        <Setter Property="Template">

                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <ListBox Name="InnerList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ></ListBox>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>

                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">button</Button>
        <ListBox Style="{StaticResource MyListStyle}" Name="ListItemsControl" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" Grid.Row="0"></ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Here is some code to load the list


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CompositeCollection cc = new CompositeCollection();
            cc.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
            cc.Add(new List<int>() { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
            cc.Add(new List<int>() { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 });
            ListItemsControl.ItemsSource = cc;



        }
```

Comment: So, the inner `ListBox` is actually inside of another `ListBox` or do you simply want to increment one `ListBox` based on the selected index of another `ListBox`?

Comment: I have a ListBox filled with Listboxes I want to be able to increment the index of an inner list box when that list box has been selected

Comment: Are you using an MVVM pattern or code-behind?

Comment: in this case code-behind but whatever works really

Comment: you have to cast it to `ListBoxItem`, not `ItemsControl`. However what you get is just a `ListBoxItem` or `null`. Looks like you should rephrase the problem, it appears that you want to access the listbox in codebehind.

Comment: @KingKing I updated the question to contain the basic template set up and the type of list bound to it. And you are correct I would like access to the inner list in code.

Comment: @Bob try casting it to `ListBoxItem` ***anyway***, if it's not null, you can use `listBoxItem.Template.FindName("InnerList", listBoxItem) as ListBox` to get the inner ListBox. However the problem is you may not get any `ListBoxItem` from `ItemContainerGenerator`, instead you get `null`. That's because of virtualizing mode. Working in virtualizing mode requires you to use Binding strictly and should not try accessing any virtual item control in codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use  a breakpoint and walk through the visualizer (little magnifying glass icon if you want over a variable) so that you may get an idea of how this code works.

Place this into your button event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //var item = ListItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1) as ListBoxItem;
    //var innerListBox = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, 0) as ListBox;
    //innerListBox.SelectedIndex++;

    // For every item in the ListItemsControl
    for (int i = 0; i < ListItemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        // Get the item container for the specified index and cast it as ListBoxItem.
        var item = ListItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) 
            as ListBoxItem;
        // Then, get the first child of the ListBoxItem and cast it as a ListBox.
        // Note that I'm making an assumption that it'll always be a ListBox,
        // which is why you should perform some checks in a production case,
        // to avoid exceptions.
        var innerListBox = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, 0) as ListBox;
        // Lastly, I increment the index of this ListBox.
        innerListBox.SelectedIndex++;
    }
}
```

Commented out is the way of changing index of just one element.  Underneath, I'm incrementing indexes of all three inner list boxes.  This gives you an idea of how to get to them, so from thereon you may alter it to your liking.  Obviously, you may want to add code to check for `null` and confirm the correct type before trying to increment the `SelectedIndex` property, but that's not very difficult.

**Old Answer (based on first post):**

This is a code-behind example.  Let me know if you want an `MVVM` one.  You may also use `Binding` to `SelectedIndex` property, but then you would have to ensure that you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented.

[image]

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="LB.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="219.965" Width="217.535">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="lbOuter" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <TextBlock>Outer Item #1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Outer Item #1</TextBlock>
                <ListBox x:Name="lbInner" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                    <ListBox.Items>
                        <TextBlock>Inner Item #1</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>Inner Item #2</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>Inner Item #3</TextBlock>
                    </ListBox.Items>
                </ListBox>
                <TextBlock>Outer Item #3</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Outer Item #4</TextBlock>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Increment Outer" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Increment Inner" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind**:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace LB
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbOuter.SelectedIndex < (lbOuter.Items.Count - 1))
            {
                lbOuter.SelectedIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                lbOuter.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbInner.SelectedIndex < (lbInner.Items.Count - 1))
            {
                lbInner.SelectedIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                lbInner.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will actually loop your selection.  So, if you reach the end, it'll take you to index 0.  You may remove that, if you don't want that functionality.

Comment: My setup is using a data template for a CompositeCollection. And I can not access the name of the ListBox set in the control template for the ItemsContainer of the out ListBox.

Comment: @Bob Ah, I was not aware of that based on your original post.

Comment: @BK I know I am sorry, I realized I was not clear in the original post and update my description.